# Standard SQL for inserting whole integers into decimal data fields?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

I'm updating an application that was coded with MYSQL 5.4 used for the database - the queries of course were affected by the old MYSQL relaxed SQL implementation and silent warning/error notices etc... I'm now using MYSQL 5.7 with default strict mode enabled. I need to insert whole integers (ie. '20') into a decimal(5,2) field. I see that the current version of MYSQL will take the value as is and add zeroed decimals to it automatically, but is this just another relaxed SQL implementation I should be wary of? I only have MYSQL to work with, so I can't compare against, say, Oracle, or SQL Server, etc. Should I be concatenating the zeroed decimal places onto the numbers? I just want to make the queries as portable as possible.

Comment: I don't see it as any issue at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're keeping the column as decimal(5,2), that will treat the incoming integer values as decimal with given precision and scale.. No need of explicit conversation required for this scenario.